# XML tags match but namespaces differ

Tags: php, xml-namespaces, soap-client, prefix, soapserver

I am trying to setup a Soap connection between a server in php and a client in C. My server is using a working wsdl file and a class to add these methods. I can confirm with Wireshark that my client request is well received and correctly processed.

My issue is that the values of the XML element sent by the server cannot be read because the namespaces differs. By adding debug log in my client I have found that the error is :

```
Tags 'state' and 'ns2:state' match but namespaces differ
```

### **Issue :**

The issue seems to be that the server response does not contain any default namespace :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/adressing"
              xmlns:ns2="http://www.namespace1/">
    <env:Body>
        <ns2:HelloResponse>
            <state>OK</state>
            <intElement>123</intElement>
        </ns2:HelloResponse>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

It looks like `<state>` and `<intElement>` are not in any namespace, so it can't match one of the client. In my Wsdl file, these element belongs to `xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"`

### **What I tried :**

Obvious solution is to add an namespace to these element, but I can't find a way to do it.
In my php server, I can modify any request that comes in but can't affect any response that comes out (or at least i didn't find how to do it).

2nd solution : Adding the namespace that describe these element to the Namespace struct in my client and then use the `set_namespace()` function.

But I couldn't manage to put them to work, please keep in mind that I am still new to the XML/Soap world, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said before, the solution was to add the corresponding namespace to these element.

I managed to do it using [ob_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.ob-get-contents.php) and adding the namespace to <ns2:HelloResponse>. Using Wireshark was really useful for this kind of stuff.